# How to specify image dimension displayed on blogger homepage

Tags: blogger

I want to speed up my blogger template of [this blog](http://bestofshayari.blogspot.com). But when i check it in gtmetrix it show one possible improvement about specifying image dimension.

Now the problem is blogger itself specifies the image resolution how can i edit it to improve the page loading speed of my blog.

Everything is well except this possible improvement.

I know if i resolve this page speed will be better.

So please help me.

Comment: Do you have access to the HTML of your homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your blogger template and find

```
.post-format{
....
...
width:
height:
}
```

change the value of width and height according to your own and you are done.

Comment: images became smaller but i want to reduce the title and description too with same height.

Answer (score 0):

ok go to blogger template and find this piece of code

```
.post-content .h3 {
```

Change the value of height and size and you are done.